# How generation and validation process works for secure token authentication?

Tags: authentication, token, access-token

I was comparing `cookie` vs `token` authentication. I'm fairly familiar with `cookie` auth, but I needed to understand how `token` auth works.

From what I understand

1. User Logins in with Username and Password
2. server gets data and checks if Username and Password match
3. If match, generates token using alg like SHA256?
4. sends token to user
5. user sends request w/ token and other data to access restricted data?
6. server uses other data and hash method to check against token?

What I'm confused by is `3`, `5`, and `6`, the token generation part.

1. For `3`, what data do you put to hash, is it just a hash or is there
   more to the process?
2. For `5`, what if any other data is sent with the token?
3. For `6`, how is the data sent used to validate the token?
4. How can you tell if the token has expired?

Answer (score 1):

> For 3, what data do you put to hash, is it just a hash or is there more to the process?

Whatever you like really. The implementation details are only of your concern. Basically, the token is a random string (encrypted, hashed or not)...again, it's up to you how you want to implement it. But, always make sure a token is unique across the system and that the system can use it to effectively identifier a user and its scope

> For 5, what if any other data is sent with the token?

I'm not too sure what else you need to send, but usually you don't have to send anything else because of what I mentioned above...an access token must describe a user (or device, or whatever) and its scope within the system. So, why would you bother sending additional information?

> For 6, how is the data sent used to validate the token?

And again, it's up to you. Other data could be the user's email address or the user id and then your system can match the userid (or email) with the access token. However, this is NOT mandatory, you can implement it whichever way you want to.

> How can you tell if the token has expired?

Well, if your system issues temporary access token, hopefully it will be keeping track of when the access token was created and then determine if the access token has expired based on the creation. That's from the server side. For example, in its simplest form, you could have a database table that stores access tokens with the following columns:

- Access Token: unique string
- UserId: the related user id
- DateCreated: UTC time

That's all you need to make it work, of course, usually you will want to provide stronger security and this table will be much bigger.